# Connecting Erlang to sqlite3 using eclipse IDE

Tags: sqlite, erlang

I am trying to connect to SQLite3 using Erlang in Eclipse IDE.

I have installed SQLite3 in `c:\Windows\System32` and am trying to connect to it using the following erlang code in Eclipse.

```
{ok, Conn} = odbc:start(),{ok, Conn} = odbc:connect("DSN=sqlite3", []).
```

I get the following error:

```
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application SQLSTATE IS: IM014 Connection to database failed.
```

Could someone please give me a step by step detail on how to resolve this error (PS: I tried using the 32 bit odbcad32 as suggested in another post, but it did not help) and how exactly do I connect to sqlite3 using erlang. Should I install any driver or include any headers? Can someone also please tell me what are the parameters I need to fill in while creating the odbc driver. I am not very familiar with Erlang or sqlite.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this https://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3. This way you will not have to handle whole ODBC thing and you will have more portable code.